# C++ Bus Error during Pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, g++, xcode7

I am trying to learn C++, esp. pointers and their arithmetic. I am using XCode to compile and run my programs.

Below i have two sets of code that attempt to create a 3D array of integers. The first code compiles and runs without errors but the second one compiles without errors but generates a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when run.

The second code generates `Bus Error: 10` when i try to compile and run from terminal using g++.

Can anyone tell me why the second set of code does not run successfully although to me it looks very similar?

CODE 1: Compile + Run Successfully

```
int main(){
    int i, j, k;
    int*** dim = new int**[3];
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        dim[i] = new int* [3];
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            *(*(dim+i)+j) = new int[3];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CODE 2: Compile Successfully but generates `EXC_BAD_ACCESS/Bus Error: 10` when run

```
int main(){
    int i, j, k;
    int*** dim = new int**[3];
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        dim[i] = new int* [3];
    }
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; i++)
            *(*(dim+i)+j) = new int[3];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Screenshot of the error:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Please don't use `new` yourself, either use a standard container like `std::vector` or [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: It's just a typo in the j loop (i++ should be j++) - fix that and it should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 8  is incrementing i instead of j:

```
for(j=0; j<3; i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for(j=0; j<3; i++)
```

increments i, not j, thus the inner loop never terminates.